# R Shiny DT shade table cells based on TRUE or FALSE

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am trying to format the background color of table cells in an R Shiny app based on the content of the cell.  The content is either TRUE or FALSE and was assigned using a boolean function. Is styleEqual() not the right way to format the cells? The following will run, but my cells remain uncolored.

```
output$myTable <-
      DT::renderDataTable({
        result<-custom_function()
        result<-
        datatable(result)%>% formatStyle(
          names(result),
          backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(TRUE, FALSE), c('green', 'red'))
        )
        return(res)
      })
```

Comment: Reproducible example will be helpful. Try define a specific column where T and F can be test to assign color.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`styleEqual` is the way to go, but you need to use numeric (`1, 0`) values instead of logical (`TRUE, FALSE`).

Here's an example:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(magrittr)

iris2 <- iris
iris2$logical <- ifelse(iris$Sepal.Length > 5, TRUE, FALSE)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput("tbl")  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$tbl <- DT::renderDataTable( {
    datatable(iris2) %>% formatStyle(
      "logical",
      target = 'row',
      backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(1, 0), c('green', 'red'))
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Thank you!  Got it to work.  You can also do an if_else statement in your dplyr mutate on the TRUE/FALSE column and set it to anything you want, like a "yes", "no" or "match", "non-match".  That's what I ended up doing.